# Genymotion: segmentation fault (core dumped) genymotion

Tags: linux, virtualbox, genymotion

I installed genymotion for works with Android SDK.

I make this [instructions](https://gist.github.com/SalahAdDin/284f42f82de735bf9a2efe8c094e2e64) step by step.

When i was installing genymotion it ask me about install `virtualbox`and them ask me about install `virtualbox-host-modules-arch` or `virtualbox-host-modules-dkms`, i choose the first.

All was installed correctly and i test genymotion installation, i sign it in genymotion and i try add new devide. but when i choose the device type and click to create genymotion get out inmediatly begins to download the device, and give me this error:

```
bash
genymotion                                                                                                                        ✓  989  12:25:11 
Logging activities to file: /home/salahaddin/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
[1]    6970 segmentation fault (core dumped)  genymotion
```

I try to search in google and i investigate the log but i don't understand why i get this error.
[image: 0_1468521234290_Selección_110.png] 
[image: 1_1468521234291_Selección_111.png]

You can see the log [here](http://pastebin.com/Y2xqjhY4).

Can anyone help me?

My SO is Antergos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve found a workaround… watching logs i saw where it takes the file for the virtual device (as it crash while downloading). So I’ve manually downloaded it in my case:

`wget http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/5.1.0/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_5.1_160609_162956.ova`

After that go to `~./Genymobile/Genymotion/ova` and place the file (here you will find the partial download started before) copy the name, delete the partial, and rename the one you manually downloaded.

The open Genymotion again, create VD and it should work.

This is a partial solution, doesn't solve the system problems but enable you to create `VD` with Genymotion.